# how to find change value of any field of a class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, event-handling

Let's say I have 2 classes `A.java` and `B.java` and there is `private int a` in A class like that :

```
public class A {
    private int a;
}
```

and I use this class in class B that I want to know or attach an handler to the field `int a`;
that to know it's value change in every asynchronous call. Let me more explain :

```
public class B {
     private A aClass;

     public static void main (String ... args) {
           aClass = new A(); // now the int a; is changed how do I know this

           // user may call many asynchronous method in class A and I want to know
           // the changing value of int a; from A class in B class
     }
}
```

Which design pattern should I use? What solution do you offer?

Thanks in advance, 
hilal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Observer pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-05/04-qa-0525-observer.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

B registers itself as the observer of A. A is the subject and B is the observer [image: in this diagram].

Whenever the "a" changes, A notify()'s all the registered Observer's.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    private B observer;

    void setA(int i) {
        a = i;
        observer.notify();
    }

    void registerObserver(B b) {
        observer = b;
    }
}
```

Add a B object in A, and recall B's method.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn class A into a [JavaBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/) and add support for PropertyListeners.
However, you first have to register one with your A() instance.